# Encryption and decryption layer for cloud storage

Tags: encryption, cloud

Cloud Storage.

So far, so good.

But what do most people want?

1) A way to encrypt their files before uploding to the cloud.

2) A way to decrypt their files transparently when accessing the cloud.

This may be some "sync" folder that get´s synced between devices (for which we have solutions like Cryptomator), but when using the cloud as storage and backup, you don´t want to need such a sync-folder.
The stuff shall be stored in the cloud, not locally - that´s the point.

Amazon Drive allows for both concepts and also can be used together with Cryptomator and sync-folder.

But what is with backups of files?

I can encrypt my videos, pictures and documents before uploading them, but then i need to download and decrypt them again!

What i - and i think most people - need, is a way to access the remotely stored, encrypted files and access them with a "decryption layer", and may it be a logical disks that i can access.

This way, i can view and edit my documents, view my picture archive and videos, and so on. All, while i do not need to download anything.

But i just cannot find such a solution!

Did i look wrong, or is this still some missing application?

Comment: "All, while i do not need to download anything."  No, some app might hide the download from you but it still needs to happen.  Download, decrypt to temp file, open with application.  If changed, re-encrypt temp file, upload.

Comment: A percentage of people are security-aware, and do not want their data accessible by the cloud provider.  The majority of people are not security-aware and will accept anything, but the risk is that breaches are more likely to happen.  If you want to be more secure, then you have an uphill battle in meeting user requirements.  A step in the right direction is [Mylar](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/popa-mylar-2016-08-29.pdf), but recent research has shown that it did not live up to all of its security claims.

Comment: Cloudberry Drive sounds like it might be what you want since it looks like it makes the copying and encryption - decryption transparent: https://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[pCloud](https://www.pcloud.com/) has an add-on encryption feature, [TeamDrive](https://www.teamdrive.com/en/) and [Tresorit](https://tresorit.com/) are also end-to-end encrypted (or at least them claim to be)